# Illustrator Save for Web preview image small and pixelated?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Recently when I Save for Web my preview image appears scaled 50% and pixelated.
However the saved image appears fine.

Is there a setting I inadvertently changed?

[image]

Comment: I don't know an official answer but in the past I've had issues with the image size going 99999px wide when loading 'Save for Web' a second time after chaning the percentage value in 'Save for Web' previously, I think it might be a bug rather than a user error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

[This article](http://www.digitalfuse.co.uk/adobe-illustrator-save-for-web-retina-pixelation/) identifies the issue as being related to retina displays and the 2x issues of high res displays. It describes a method of removing preferences, reinstalling Illustrator and then creating new Save For Web preferences before updating Illustrator. And then forbids you from using Adobe's auto update features. This is more than I would do, so ...

I would just change the preview zoom to 200%, which makes the preview the size that the actual artwork is and final artwork will be. This is not ideal since you have to change the zoom every time you open the Save For Web dialog box, but it works.

As far as I can tell this is an Illustrator bug that Adobe needs to fix.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely set up your document as a print document which defaults to measure by points instead of pixels which is what save for web is designed to output for.

simply increase the pixels on the save for web interface and it will output larger.

Comment: Adobe applications equate pixels and points. 72 points is the same as 72 pixels throughout the suite.

Answer (score -4):

Try unchecking Clip to Artboard, your art board may be bigger than your artwork.